# Mark task as complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Simple to-do list application. Having difficulty marking tasks as complete without ajax. My approach was to create a "completed" column in the task model which is a boolean. Then define complete and incomplete tasks in the controller and create routes accordingly. This does not seems to work and i am not sure why. Can someone let me know if i am doing it wrong ? I am open to suggestions and alternatives please. cheers.

Task model with scoped options.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title
  #validates_presence_of :user_id
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  belongs_to :user
  scope :completed, where(:completed =>true)
  scope :incomplete, where(:completed =>false)
end
```

Routes file

```
match '/tasks/complete/:id' => 'tasks#complete', as: 'complete_task', via: :put
match '/tasks/complete/:id' => 'tasks#incomplete', as: 'incomplete_task', via: :delete
```

Tasks controller

```
  def complete
   @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
   @task.completed = true
   @task.save
   redirect_to current_user
 end

 def incomplete
  @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
  @task.completed = false
  @task.save
  redirect_to current_user
end
```

Tasks index View

```
<h3>Incompleted tasks</h3>
 <% current_user.tasks.incomplete.each do |task| %>
 <p><%= task.title %>|
 <%= link_to "Done", complete_task_path(task), method: :put %></p>
<% end %>

<h3>Completed tasks</h3>
 <% current_user.tasks.completed.each do |task| %>
 <p><%= task.title %>|
 <%= link_to "Undo", incomplete_task_path(task), method: :delete %></p>
<% end %>
```

Also i am running rails 4.

Comment: are you getting any error in complete action ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the "this does not work" part, what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written here: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Through Rails 4 you have to use the following syntax:

```
scope :completed, -> { where(completed: true) }
```